# JavaScript For-Loop alter loop statement in closure

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, closures, settimeout

I have a for-loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0, ii = 10; i < ii; i++) {
    var timer = setTimeout(function(i,timer) {
        return function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            if (condition) ii++;
        }
    }(i,timer), 1000);
}
```

What I am trying to do is increase the amount of times the for-loop is executed inside of the delayed closure in that for-loop.

The problem is that by the time that one of the 10 timer functions is executed, the loop has already finished. (I assume this is the problem)

I would like to know how I can alter `ii` within a such `timeout` function, without having to call the entire for-loop again. (The process has to stay in one loop)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do what you want exactly like that because whatever function is passed to `setTimeout` won't execute until the current function completes. For example, if you try:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Hello!');
}, 100);
while (true) { }
```

You'll never see `'Hello!'` because the current function will never complete. Instead, you might consider creating a function such that it acts upon something given your `ii` variable.

```
function doStuff(ii) {
    // Do some stuff given ii
    if (condition) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            doStuff(ii + 1);
        }, 1000);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    doStuff(i);
}
```